# How to make asp.net member provider and entity framework share the same database

Tags: entity-framework-4, asp.net-membership, sql-server-ce

I have a clean MVC 3 project and using SqlCe membership provider for security accounts.

When i specify the in the connection string that the Membership provider and Entity framework to use the same "database" i would get a table not found error in the EF Code First model

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|db.sdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCE.4.0" />
    <add name="SqlDbContext" connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|db.sdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCE.4.0" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

However if i specify different database names then i would work perfectly - Although it creates two seperate SDF files.  The following connection strings works:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|aspnet.sdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCE.4.0" />
    <add name="SqlDbContext" connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|db.sdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCE.4.0" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Why does it only work when i specify two seperate SDF tables? And how can i utilise a single SDF database for the membership provider and ef models?

Comment: Do you create database tables for EF manually?

Comment: No, I'm using the code first approach so expecting the tables to be automatically created - In fact the tables are automatically created using the 2nd config

Answer (score 1):

The reason for your problem is code first internal logic for table creation. All versions except EF 5.0 RC will create tables only together with database. If database exists and you are not using initialization strategy which is able to drop database your tables will not be created. In turn if you use the strategy for dropping database you will lose your membership tables.

You can either create [custom database initializer](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/gilf/archive/2011/05/30/creating-a-code-first-database-initializer-strategy.aspx) creating tables in existing database or custom database initializer which will execute DDL script for creating membership tables in Seed method or you can try [EF 5.0 RC](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2012/05/15/ef5-release-candidate-available-on-nuget.aspx) which should be able to create tables in existing database out-of-the box.

Alternatively you can also let code first to create database first and then add membership tables manually but every time you let code first recreate database (when not using migrations) it will delete your membership table and you will have to add them manually again.

Answer (score 0):

I'm in the midst of rolling my own membership/role/profile admin for a site I'm working on and came across this question. I'm a little late for this question, but this link should help you if you're still working on this:
http://imar.spaanjaars.com/563/using-entity-framework-code-first-and-aspnet-membership-together

HTH